# SSH.NET UploadFile not releasing file lock

Tags: .net, vb.net, sftp, ssh.net

I'm using the SSH.NET SFTP functionality to upload a file to an SFTP. I have written it into a function however the issue I appear to have is after the upload has completed and I try to move the original file I'm getting a File is being used by another process.

I know this is the upload process not releasing the file as I have commented the upload function out and everything works as expected.

Any pointers on my code as to what my issue is would be greatly appreciated.

```
Private Function UploadFile(ByVal file As String, ByVal branch As String, ByVal policyref As String) As Boolean

    Dim connInfo As New ConnectionInfo("abc:22", "guestuser", New PasswordAuthenticationMethod("guestuser", "password"))

    Using client As New SftpClient(connInfo)

        client.Connect()
        If client.IsConnected Then
            Console.WriteLine("Connected to sFTP")
        End If

        Dim fileStream As New FileStream(file, FileMode.Create)

        client.UploadFile(fileStream, "/Test/" & Path.GetFileName(file))

        If client.Exists("/Test/" & Path.GetFileName(file)) Then
            Console.WriteLine("File Uploaded - " & Path.GetFileName(file))
            UpdateFTPLog(branch, policyref)
            Return True
        End If

        client.Disconnect()
        client.Dispose()

    End Using

    Return False
End Function
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It has nothing to do with SSH.NET. It is a fault of your own code. You never dispose the `fileStream`.

It should be:

```
Using fileStream As FileStream = New FileStream(file, FileMode.Create)
    client.UploadFile(fileStream, "/Test/" & Path.GetFileName(file))
End Using
```

Comment: Marvelous - Thank you for pointing that out Martin - I'd overlooked it when relooking through my code. Another pair of eyes help.